# Routing questions with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am just starting with rails and I have a very simple case. I have a "home" controller. There is one action 'index' defined in this controller. When I go to ~/home I get an error msg saying:

`uninitialized constant HomesController` (I noticed the singular/plural thing).

That's the first thing I don't get (I thought it would automatically go to ~/home/index).

Second thing, if I go to `~/home/edit` (note that this action doesn't exist yet), I get also:
`uninitialized constant HomesController`
But if I go to ~/home/show (show doesn't exist as well) I get a different error message:

```
No route matches "/home/show"
```

How can I get 2 differents errors for the same reason (an inexistant action). And What's the deal with this constant?

Thank you

**Edit** 
I'm running rails 3.0

Here is my routes.rb file

```
Topnotch::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :subscriptions
  resource :home

  get "home/index"

  get "subscriptions/index"

  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

Comment: what version of rails are you running and what do you currently have in `routes.rb`?

Comment: rails 3. I've just edited the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the routes were correct I was just not using them correctly !
`rake routes` helped.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must add the resource "home" to the route.rb.
2. The controllers are considered to be plural.
3. If you are new to rails, I suggest you to start using generators - just open a terminal in the project's folder and type in "script/generate scaffold home" (in rails3 it would be "rails g home")

Comment: I used the generator to generate a controller (I didn't need a model for my home controller!). Also, I already have a resource for home in route.rb). Am I obliged to choose a plural name for the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Changes the root route as below:-

root :to => "homes#index".

You must use the plural form in the routes.